# How to link a TableViewController with another TableView

Tags: ios

I have a TableView and TableCell embedded in TableViewController in storyboard already working properly. My goal is to add one TableView and TableCell to another UIView. This UIView is controlled by a UIViewController. Naively I am thinking that I should be able to add a TableView within the UIView and somehow connect this TableView to be controlled by my TableViewController.

How do I do that?

Comment: I think you should use another TableViewController again because if you are using a view you need to embed it to another superView and I think you will be doing to much. So use Two TableViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible workaround. In your `UIViewController` you make a property `tableViewController` of the type of your `TableViewController`.

Then initialise your TableViewController from inside the `UIViewController`, for example:

```
if (!self.tableViewController) self.tableViewController = [TableViewController new];
```

then take `tableViewController.tableView` and add it as a `subView` to your `UIView`.

```
[self.view addSubView: self.tableViewController.tableView];
```

When you need to remove it, just do

```
[self.tableViewController.tableView removeFromSuperView];
```

you could also add `self.tableViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` after the creation of `TableViewController`.